# How to horizontally center an img in a div with a span beside it?

Tags: html, css

As the title says, I would like to center an img in a div with a span beside it. The HTML is as follows:

```
<div>
    <img src="http://www.openwebanalytics.com/wp-content/plugins/owa/modules/base/i/browsers/128x128/ie4.png">
    <span>Text</span>
</div>
```

This is as far as I've gotten: https://jsfiddle.net/qhpfoqng/2/. As you can see, it centers BOTH as if they were one element, when I really just want it to center the img only. The end product should have the img centered horizontally in the div with the span to the right of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the `span` from the document flow by setting `position: absolute;` and then use some CSS magic to position it where you want it to be:

```css
div {
  width: 350px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px black solid;
}

img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

span {
  font-size: 200%;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://www.openwebanalytics.com/wp-content/plugins/owa/modules/base/i/browsers/128x128/ie4.png">
  <span>Text</span>
</div>
```

For that method to work, the surrounding `div` needs to be positioned (any position value other than the default `static`).

https://jsfiddle.net/qhpfoqng/4/

Comment: Ofc it did, why would I answer otherwise? :D

Answer (score 1):

Add the css as follows:

```
div {
  margin:0 auto;
  width: 350px;
  text-align: center;  
  border: 1px black solid;     
}
```

[jsFiddel Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/qhpfoqng/3/)

Comment: You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

1. Give **width** in percentage to your image
2. Then add **margin-left** also in percentage in way **margin-left = 100% - image_width / 2**

For this example, I used **width: 40%**, that means **100% - 40% / 2 = 30%**; so **margin-left: 30%**, and that will center your image.

```
    div {
      width: 350px;

      border: 1px black solid;
    }

    img {
      width: 40%;
      margin-left: 30%;
      vertical-align: middle;
    }

    span {
      font-size: 200%;
    }
```